# Why does the Meteor todo tutorial use a dot in it's method property names (e.g., 'tasks.insert')?

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

I'm going through the Meteor "todo" tutorial, and am at the part "9. Security with Methods":

https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/security-with-methods

```
Meteor.methods({
   'tasks.insert'(text) {  // <----- That bit right there!
      check(text, String);
      if (! this.userId) {
         // ...
      }

      //...etc...
```

I get that the single-quotes are there because there is a special character in the property name. But my question is, is that special character really necessary? Why not just use a more straightforward property name like "tasks_insert" so that no single-quotes are needed? Is this just a style choice, or is that dot syntax important?

Comment: Yes, it is a convention, and as for the `this` context, see the [docs](https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-methods).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a style choice, to represent that it's a method named `insert` belonging to a `tasks` module. It's not necessary to use the dot.

The `this` refers to a special "method invocation object" with useful variables set:

From http://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-methods:

> Inside your method invocation, `this` is bound to a method invocation object, which provides the following:
>
> - `isSimulation`: a boolean value, true if this invocation is a stub.
> - `unblock`: when called, allows the next method from this client to begin running.
> - `userId`: the id of the current user.
> - `setUserId`: a function that associates the current client with a user.
> - `connection`: on the server, the connection this method call was received on.